# What does "five chins" mean in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Dudley had spent most of the summer in the kitchen, his piggy little eyes fixed on the screen and his **five chins** wobbling as he ate continually.

As I understand, "**five chins**" is hyperbole implying Dudley is extremely fat. Am I getting it right?

What does it mean exactly?

Comment: Yes, you're getting it right. Dudley has only one real chin but he's so fat that he got five folds of skin around his neck that look like extra chins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/double-chin)

> **double chin:** a fold of skin under the face along the front of the
>   neck, caused by a layer of fat

By taking it further and saying Dudley has 5 chins, the author is implying that not only is Dudley fat, he is VERY fat.